# Parse JSON response with nested values (sometimes nonevalues)

Tags: python, json, parsing, list-comprehension

I'm trying to parse multiple JSON responses from an API request using Python (one example below, but I have a list containing hundreds of these JSON responses). I'm looking to create a dictonary with the values from the `"dealID", "companyName", and "dealSize": "amount"` keys.

I'm able to successfully create a dictionary containing values from the first 3 keys above, but not the nested `"amount"`. The issue I'm running into is that `"amount"` sometimes has a none value. To get around this, I created a function that replaces the none value with a default value. But now when I try to create a dictionary, I'm getting the error message `"TypeError: string indices must be integers"`. Grateful for any advice. I've seemingly tried everything.

```
[{
    "dealId": "330843-24T",
    "dealNumber": 1,
    "companyId": "62224",
    "companyName": "Company A",
    "dealDate": "2014-04-16",
    "dealSize": {
        "amount": 1500000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 1500000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "dealSizeStatus": "Actual",
    "dealStatus": {
        "code": "COMP",
        "description": "Completed"
    },
    "percentAcquired": "None",
    "raisedToDate": {
        "amount": 1500000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 1500000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "vcRound": "1st Round",
    "vcRoundUpDownFlat": "None",
    "totalInvestedCapital": {
        "amount": 1500000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 1500000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "investorOwnership": "None",
    "stockSplit": "None",
    "dealType1": {
        "code": "Seed",
        "description": "Seed Round"
    },
    "dealType2": "None",
    "dealType3": "None",
    "dealClass": {
        "code": "VC",
        "description": "Venture Capital"
    },
    "dealSynopsis": "The company raised $1.5 million of seed funding",
    "totalInvestedEquity": {
        "amount": 300000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 300000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "debtType1": "None",
    "debtType2": "None",
    "debtType3": "None",
    "debtAmount1": {
        "amount": 1200000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 1200000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "debtAmount2": "None",
    "debtAmount3": "None",
    "debtRaisedInRound": {
        "amount": 1200000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 1200000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "contingentPayout": "None",
    "valuationAvailable": true,
    "capTableAvailable": false,
    "trancheInfoAvailable": false,
    "debtLenderInfoAvailable": true
}, {
    "dealId": "4053346-57T",
    "dealNumber": 3,
    "companyId": "624245-02",
    "companyName": "Company A",
    "dealDate": "2017-02-27",
    "dealSize": {
        "amount": 2800000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 2800000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "dealSizeStatus": "Actual",
    "dealStatus": {
        "code": "COMP",
        "description": "Completed"
    },
    "percentAcquired": "None",
    "raisedToDate": {
        "amount": 14298988.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 14298988.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "vcRound": "3rd Round",
    "vcRoundUpDownFlat": "None",
    "totalInvestedCapital": {
        "amount": 2800000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 2800000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "investorOwnership": "None",
    "stockSplit": "None",
    "dealType1": {
        "code": "EVC",
        "description": "Early Stage VC"
    },
    "dealType2": {
        "code": "A1",
        "description": "Series A1"
    },
    "dealType3": "None",
    "dealClass": {
        "code": "VC",
        "description": "Venture Capital"
    },
    "dealSynopsis": "The company raised $2.8 million",
    "totalInvestedEquity": {
        "amount": 2800000.0,
        "currency": "USD",
        "nativeAmount": 2800000.0,
        "nativeCurrency": "USD",
        "estimated": false
    },
    "debtType1": "None",
    "debtType2": "None",
    "debtType3": "None",
    "debtAmount1": "None",
    "debtAmount2": "None",
    "debtAmount3": "None",
    "debtRaisedInRound": "None",
    "contingentPayout": "None",
    "valuationAvailable": false,
    "capTableAvailable": false,
    "trancheInfoAvailable": false,
    "debtLenderInfoAvailable": false
},
```

This is the function I've used to replace the none values in the original list (called dealinfo) containing the JSON responses

```
def replace_none_in_ddict(dealinfo):
    replacement = "0"
    return {k: v if v is not None else replacement for k, v in dealinfo}

json_str = json.dumps(dealinfo)
dealinfo2 = json.loads(json_str, object_pairs_hook=replace_none_in_ddict)
dealinfo3 = json.dumps(dealinfo2)
```

And this is my attempt to create a dictionary that results in the string TypeError. `dealinfo3` contains the JSON responses with the none values replaced with 0.

```
elements = []
for data in dealinfo3: 
    dealdata = {   
         
        "DealID" : data["dealId"],
        "Deal_Size": data["dealSize"]["amount"],
        "CompanyID" : data["companyId"],        
   }
    elements.append(dealdata)
```

Comment: *To get around this, I created a function that replaces the none value with a default value. But now when I try to create a dictionary, I'm getting the error message "TypeError: string indices must be integers".* -- well, if your wish is to get that code working, you should consider showing it.

Comment: Added more of my code to the OP. I am new to coding and wasn't sure how much information to include in the question. I was trying to strike the balance between providing enough info for people to be able answer the question and not providing too much info so as to discourage readers. Guess I fell on the wrong side of that line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure exactly the output you want.

if the output like this:

[{'dealID': '330843-24T', 'companyName': 'Company A', 'dealSize': 1500000.0}, {'dealID': '4053346-57T', 'companyName': 'Company A', 'dealSize': 2800000.0}]

so the code like this:

```
keys_needed = ['dealID', 'companyName', 'dealSize']

grand_dict = []
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    i = {'dealID': '',
            'companyName': '',
            'dealSize': ''}
            
    i['dealID'] = d.get('dealId')
    i['companyName'] = d.get('companyName')
    i['dealSize'] = d.get('dealSize') and d.get('dealSize').get('amount')
    grand_dict.append(i)

print (grand_dict)
```

Comment: ```[{'DealID': '330563-47T', 'Deal_Size': 1500000.0, 'CompanyID': '62222-03'}, {'DealID': '40532-77T', 'Deal_Size': 2800000.0, 'CompanyID': '62427-03'}, {'DealID': '80414-40T', 'Deal_Size': 9998988.0, 'CompanyID': '62428-03'}, {'DealID': '107900-92T', 'Deal_Size': 400000.0, 'CompanyID': '226224-24'}```

This is an example of my intended output. The intention is then to create a pivot table from this (which I am currently able to do with "dealSize", but it contains the other nested key/values that I don't want).

Comment: @Pballer88, alright, i Updated the code

Comment: The code does exactly what I need it to do. Thanks so much for taking the time to help. I'd been stuck on this issue for a couple of weeks now and had been using complex, time consuming workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a minimal example of your input-data like this:

```
input_data = [
    {
        "dealId": "330843-24T",
        "companyName": "Company A",
        "dealSize": {
            "amount": 1500000.0,
        }},
    {
        "dealId": "4053346-57T",
        "companyName": "Company A",
        "dealSize": {
            "amount": None,
        }
    }]
```

How do you want to replace your None values? In this solution dealSize is set to 0, if the amount is None.
Feel free to ask any question or correct me if my assumptions were wrong :)

```
output = [{"dealId": deal.get("dealId"), 
           "companyName": deal.get("companyName"), 
           "dealSize": deal.get("dealSize", {}).get("amount") or 0} for deal in input_data]
```

output:

```
[{'dealId': '330843-24T', 'companyName': 'Company A', 'dealSize': 1500000.0}, 
 {'dealId': '4053346-57T', 'companyName': 'Company A', 'dealSize': 0}]
```

EDIT: copy/paste

```
input_data = [
    {
        "dealId": "330843-24T",
        "companyName": "Company A",
        "dealSize": {
            "amount": 1500000.0,
        }},
    {
        "dealId": "4053346-57T",
        "companyName": "Company A",
        "dealSize": {
            "amount": None,
        }
    }]

output = [{"dealId": deal.get("dealId"),
           "companyName": deal.get("companyName"),
           "dealSize": deal.get("dealSize", {}).get("amount") or 0} for deal in input_data]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. 

Replacing the nonevalues with 0 will be fine. I've tried your suggested solution, but unfortunately, I'm running into another error:  

```output = [{"dealId": deal.get("dealId"), 
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'``` 

Could this be something to do with the type format of my input_data?

Comment: I've edited the answer and added the whole example. Please try to copy/paste and take a look if it works for you. If it does, replace `input_data`with your input. If that does not work, please tell me at which line it fails.

Comment: I think a rather significant part of the question is how to parse JSON `{"amount": "None"}` into a Python dictionary `{"amount": None}`. Which these attempts treat as the starting point.

Comment: None is not "None" but null in json. Example: `json.dumps({"amount": None})  ` 
 `'{"amount": null}'`

Comment: @bitflip

It's the first of the line of the output list that is encountering the error. 

```line 104, in <module> output = [{"dealId": deal.get("dealId"), 
line 104, in <listcomp>output = [{"dealId": deal.get("dealId"),
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'```

Answer (score 1):

There is "[", what means this json inside the list.
You need modify every element:

```
for my_json in some_json:
    print(my_json['argument'])
```

example:

```
response = r.get(url)
response_text = json.loads(response.text)
for responce_json in responce_text:
    lat = responce_json['lat']
    lon = responce_json['lon']
```